# 警告の解決方法が知りたい。「The method start() from the type MainActivity is never used locally」

Tags: android, java

private void start() の部分で、「The method start() from the type MainActivity is never used locally」という警告が出ています。どう修正すべきかご教示いただけないでしょうか。

```
package com.jp.hoge;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
// マニフェストに <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> を追加すること。
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private Timer timer;

    private void start() {
        // タイマーの初期化
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                // タイマーの実行回数
                private int i;

                // 信号強度の合計
                private double sum;

                // 信号強度の取得部分。
                private double getStrength() {
                    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                    String[] apInfo = new String[4];
                    int rssi = info .getRssi();
                    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
                    apInfo[3] = String.format("RSSI : %d / Level : %d/4", rssi, level);
                    return rssi;
                }

                // タイマー実行時に呼び出される。
                // 1秒間隔で信号強度を取得し、10回に1回送信を行う
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // 実行回数が5, 15, 25, 35…であれば送信
                        if (++i % 10 == 5) {
                            // URLの生成部分。http://192.168.0.2/index.php?RSSI=80 といった具合に、RSSIを引数で渡す。
                            URL url = new URL(
                                    "http://192.168.0.2/index.php?RSSI=" + Math.round(sum / 5));
                            HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                            // 送信
                            cn.getResponseCode();

                            // 切断
                            cn.disconnect();
                        }

                        // 実行回数が5の倍数であれば強度の和をリセット
                        if (i % 5 == 0) {
                            sum = 0;
                        }

                        // 現在の強度を加算
                        sum += getStrength();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO エラー処理
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000); // 上のrunを0ミリ秒後から1000ミリ秒間隔で実行する
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        // タイマーの停止
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private`で宣言したメソッドはそのクラス内からしか呼べませんが、このコードでは誰も呼び出していないため「使われていないメソッドがあります」という警告を出しているのです。

解決するには

- 単に`start()`メソッドを呼び出す処理を書く
- メソッドのスコープを広げる（`protected`や`public`にすれば使われる可能性が出るため警告が消えます）
- `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`アノテーションで警告を抑制する（デバッグ用途のメソッドや、リフレクションで動的に呼び出すコードに警告が出ないようにできます）

などの方法があります。

Comment: start()メソッドは宣言したが、呼び出しの処理がすっぽり抜けている、ということですね。
アプリを起動したら自動で呼び出すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか・・・。

Comment: `Activity`のライフサイクルについて、調べるといいかもしれません。アプリが表示されている間だけタイマを動かすなら、`onResume()`で開始して`onPause()`に停止処理を入れます。ずっと動かすなら`onCreate()`で`start()`させてしまってもいいのですが、バッテリ消費などを考える必要があります。

Comment: @hayaMAX 「アプリ起動と同時に定期的処理を開始したい」は「警告が出ないようにしたい」というQ&Aには収まりきらない問題だと思いますので、改めて質問を投稿されるとよいかと思います。

Comment: @ento そうさせていただきます。どうもありがとうございます。